# Selecting title, description and keywords from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding a tiny search engine for my practice. I want to add up search functionality in it. I am trying to select all rows of `questions` table upon matching title, description and keywords.

I created the following 3 tables:

```
questions(id(PK), title, description)

keywords(id(PK), label);

questions_keywords(id(PK), question_id(FK), keyword_id(FK));
```

So far my SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT q.* FROM question_keywords qk 
JOIN keywords k ON qk.keyword_id=k.id 
JOIN questions q ON qk.question_id=q.id 
WHERE q.description LIKE '%javascript%' 
OR 
k.keyword_label LIKE '%java%'
```

In this query, i am selecting all the rows from `questions` table containing the substring `java` or `javascript`

Am I doing it right or there is a better way to do it??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will probably need to use `SELECT DISTINCT q.*`, because your query can generate duplicate rows.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yeah. I also noticed. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: where are the `keywords` in your table?  I don't see them, do you mean `keywords.label`?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes correct.

Answer (score 0):

AS others mentioned I would add distinct. I would also reorder the tables. Functionally I don't think it matters it just bugged me... ha ha

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    q.*
FROM
    questions AS q
JOIN
    question_keywords AS qk ON q.id = qk.question_id
JOIN
    keywords AS k ON qk.keyword_id = k.id
WHERE
    q.description LIKE '%javascript%'
OR
    k.label LIKE '%java%';
```

As you can see in this DBfiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pcVqcMm1yUoU6NdSHitCVr/2

The reason you get duplicates is basically called a Cartesian product

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

In simple terms is just a consequence of having a "Many to Many" relationship.

If you see in the fiddle I intentionally created this situation by what I added to the Bridge ( or Junction ) table `question_keywords` in the last 2 Inserts

```
INSERT INTO question_keywords (question_id,keyword_id)VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO question_keywords (question_id,keyword_id)VALUES(4,2);
```

The duplicate row, is simply because there are `2` entries for this table with the matching value of `4` for `question_id`.  So these are only `Duplicates` in the sense that we are only selecting the fields form the `questions` table.  If we included fields from the keywords table.  Then one row would have a keyword or `Java #1` while the other would have `Javascript #2` as the keyword.

Hope that helps explain it.

A few other things to note:

1. You have a syntax error in the query you posted `k.keyword_label LIKE '%java%'` should be `k.label LIKE '%java%'` according to your table definition in the question.
2. Typically the Junction table should be a combination of both tables it joins ( which you almost did ) but the pluralization is wrong `question_keywords` should be `questions_keywords` it's a small thing but it could cause confusion when writing queries.
3. There is really not a need for a separate primary key for the Junction table.

If you notice how I created the table in the fiddle.

```
CREATE TABLE question_keywords( 
    question_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    keyword_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(question_id,keyword_id)
);
```

The primary key is a compound of the 2 foreign keys.  This has the added benefit of preventing real duplicate rows from being made. For example if you tried this

```
INSERT INTO question_keywords (question_id,keyword_id)VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO question_keywords (question_id,keyword_id)VALUES(4,1);
```

With the setup I have it would be impossible to create the duplicate.  You can still have a separate primary key (surrogate key), but you should create a compound unique index on those 2 keys in place of it.